# Алгоритм "похожих записей"

Tags: алгоритм, php, mysql

Задача, в общем, такая:

Необходимо выводить похожие записи на основе заголовков из MySQL.

Наверное, знакомо, практически в любой CMS существует такой модуль, а ковыряться в коде как-то лениво, да и большинство там реализовано на основе тегов, а мне такой способ не подходит.
Подкиньте идей, хотя бы текстом, необязательно кодом.

Comment: идея №1 посмотреть как это реализовано "практически в любой CMS" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, имеется в виду поиск по базе в текстовом поле (или `varchar`) похожих слов.
Например:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%$part%'");
```

где `title` - заголовок.

Например:

```
$z; // приходящая фраза (состоит из слов)
foreach(explode(' ',$z) as $part){
if(strlen($part)>3){ // всякие мелкие слова не учитываем
$part = mysql_real_escape_string($part);
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE '%$part%'");
//..... ну и тут детали
// в общем, все записи которые будут - это те, которые содержат то что нужно
}
}
```

`$part` - это слово из приходящего заголовка.

Comment: Может это и имеется ввиду, но реализовывается это явно не так. С большими объемами данных вы убьете базу на нет такими запросами. Тут как минимум индексирование нужно.

Comment: Да и еще ошибка в коде. 
`mysql_real_excape_string` -> `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Да, на больших запросах все сложнее. Но давайте тогда тут поговорим и о memcached, распределенных серверах, нагрузках на MySQL и т.п.

вот что за манера - ходить и тролить ответы... 
Пишите свой ответ, коли у вас "реализовывается это явно не так". А мы тут поглядим, как бы У ВАС не проскочила какая-нибудь "Да и еще ошибка..."

Comment: По хорошему надо проводить "языковое" преобразование каждого слова (морфологическое ? (не помню точно)) т.е. отбрасывать окончания и возможно некоторые суффиксы и приставки. Это надо делать делать с помещаемым в базу текстом, а также со словами Вашего запроса по одинаковому алгоритму.

Также желательно использовать некий тематический словарь (тезаурус) и работать только со словами из него (отсеиваем мусор).

В принципе можно сделать пополнение тезауруса. Т.е. "мусор" некоторое время накапливвается, а потом администратор системы принимает решение о пополнении тезауруса. 

(Места мало....)

Comment: Латентно-семантический анализ

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [здесь](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/477.cfm). Там описано решение явно лучше, чем через like. И вообще использовать like очень не рекомендую.

Лучше [здесь](http://phpclub.ru/mysql/doc/fulltext-search.html) посмотрите. Тут по-русски черным по белому.